# How to custom my primary key value in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to custom the primary key value for my `Staff Info` database. SQL Server will auto generate a `StaffID` (PK) which starts from 1, 2, 3..... and so on.

But I don't want that, can I set it to generate the `StaffID` (PK) such as ST20001 or ST01 instead of just 1,2,3?

Comment: Just have a primary key that is not an indentity column, and provide the values yourself. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you generate it with code at insertion time? Yes. Will the system do it for you automatically using your special formula? Not likely but requirements defined with "like" are not very precise. Is this a good idea? Probably not. Perhaps all you need is a computed column that concatenates your prefix with a zero-filled value based on an identity or sequence.

Comment: If ST is a fixed prefix then why does it need to be stored in every row? Just store the integer like normal and format the output with ST and leading zeros _only when you need to show it that way_. You can do this with a computed column, a view, etc. Also need to consider what you do when you hit 99999.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need to store this in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Staff
(
  StaffID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  StaffIDForDisplay AS ('ST' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',9) + CONVERT(varchar(11), StaffID)))
);
GO

INSERT dbo.Staff DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 3

SELECT * FROM dbo.Staff;
```

Results:

```
StaffID    StaffIDForDisplay
=======    =================
1          ST0000000001
2          ST0000000002
3          ST0000000003
```

You can do similar with a view, or you could simply add/remove the `ST0000...` at the client when needed.